# Can I get word suggestions on Mac like I do on iPhone?

Tags: mac, text, spelling

Let me explain what I mean. I'm not talking about autocorrect, which I really hate! What I mean is when I type something on my Mac I’ll often get a suggestion like so:

[image]

But on iPhone if I do the same thing I’ll get 3 suggestions to choose from AND they're not in the way. This is great for when I'm not sure how to spell something.

Can I get the same thing on my Mac too? I want to be able to get more than 1 suggestion for when I don't know how to spell something.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Yes, you certainly can!** Just start typing your word and press <kbd>F5</kbd> to reveal up to 20 possible words. To use your example, below is a screenshot showing how this works when I type `envir` and press the <kbd>F5</kbd> key:

[image]

You can then use the arrow keys (or mouse) to select the word you want (or just hit <kbd>enter</kbd> to accept the first word).

And, because this only appears when you press <kbd>F5</kbd>, it's not getting in your way (i.e. it only appears when you **want** it to appear).

**NOTES:**

- The <kbd>F5</kbd> key should work in all Apple apps (e.g. TextEdit, Notes, Mail, Pages, Numbers, Keynote, etc) although there are some instances where it won't. For example, within Safari it works in the Address/Search bar, but probably won't work within forms/fields on web pages.
- Support by 3rd party apps depends on the developer and/or whether the <kbd>F5</kbd> key is already allocated to something else. For example, many Microsoft apps already use <kbd>F5</kbd> to bring up the Find and Replace window, so <kbd>F5</kbd> won't work to bring up suggestions. However, other 3rd party apps do support it (e.g. Mactracker, PDF Expert, 1Password, Evernote, etc).
- Depending on your System Preferences and/or Mac model (or type of keyboard) you may need to press <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>F5</kbd> to bring up suggestions.

Comment: Hmm. Does the F5 trick work outside of Text-Edit?

Comment: @Josh Good question! I've just added some notes to the end of my answer. :)

Comment: Interesting. Seems like that would be a useful feature in a Safari form...Off to AppleScript... Anyway Thanks.

Comment: In some apps, including TextEdit and Script Editor, <kbd>Esc</kbd> does the same thing. Also, is there a way to trigger this without <kbd>F5</kbd>? Perhaps a menu bar item or scriptable command?

Comment: @BallpointBen Hmm, I couldn't get the ESC key to work in this way in TextEdit or Script Editor. Perhaps it's a setting somewhere or the fact I'm  mainly on High Sierra? As for being able to trigger this another way, good question! I'll do some digging and see what I can find.

Answer (score 14):

If you have a Touch Bar, you can enable ‘Touch Bar typing suggestions’. This shows the same 3 options you're used to on iOS on the Touch Bar as you type. This will also show emoji suggestions like iOS.

[image]
[image]

Enable it from System Preferences → Keyboard → Text → Touch Bar typing suggestions.

[image: Touch Bar typing suggestions option in System Preferences → Keyboard]

Answer (score 4):

Going off of what @grg said, if you don't have the Touch Bar you can use [a Touch Bar Simulator](https://github.com/sindresorhus/touch-bar-simulator).

This will give you an on screen Touch Bar with the typing suggestions as @grg explained.

Comment: If you don't want a third-party app, Xcode also has a touch bar simulator.

Comment: @seaturtle Yes, I think this App is the Xcode simulator but without Xcode. So you don’t have to install Xcode.

Comment: Yeah, I posted this before I looked at the app's project page and read the description. (:

Comment: Ok, but how do you select the suggestions? Clicking them manually is clearly not a viable solution.